# handling cookie expiration in multithreaded Rest client

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, rest, threadpool

I have a service I am writing that sits between clients that will take bulk requests and send them individually to a vendor application that needs that broken out to individual requests.

That vendor application has a rest API that has a token hat expires every 4 hours. It also expires on reboot, and for a variety of other situations.  I would like to handle this gracefully.

For performance reasons, I have profiled that I can send 15 concurrent requests to the vendor application, so that I do not have to wait for the full round trip.

The issue I am trying to solve now is how to handle the case of the token/cookie expiration when I am in the middle of a bulk operation.

My code looks roughly like this, Executor and many other things excluded for brevity:

```
@RestController("/upload")
public BulkController {

    @Autowired RestClient restClient;

    @PostMapping
    public bulkUpload(@RequestBody BulkType bulk){
        restClient.bulkupload(bulk);
    }
}

public RestClient {
    /* Credentials and other initializations */
    @Autowired AsnycClient asyncClient;
    @Async
    private 
    public bulkupload(BulkType bulk){
        for( Single single: bulk.getEntries()){
            asyncClient.upload(single);
        }
    }

}
public AsnycClient {

    /* Credentials and other initializations */
    private static String token = null;
    @Async
    public uploadSingle(Single single){

        Result result = vendorClient.upload(single, token);
        if( result.needsAuthentication()){
            token = vendorClient.authenticate(credentials);
            result = vendorClient.upload(single, token);
        }
    }

}
```

The part I am hung up on is how to handle the case where the token has expired, or been invalidated, on the first request of this bulk process.

What is happening now, is that the first 10 or so request get sent with the old token, and they all come back with `needsAuthentication(true)`.  So I get 10 calls to `authenticate()` and 10 more calls to the vendor application again, for 30 total calls.

What I'd like to try to find is the right way to get the `authenticate()` to happen properly, so that the first 1 of those that has `needsAuthentication(true)` performs `authenticate()` and the other ones are able to detect that somehow, and use the new value of token.

The naive way which got me to my question, is just running this:

```
public AsnycClient {

    /* Credentials and other initializations */
    private static String token = null;
    @Async
    public uploadSingle(Single single){
        Result result = vendorClient.upload(single, token);
        if( result.needsAuthentication()){
            synchronized (token){
                token = vendorClient.authenticate(credentials);
            }
            result = vendorClient.upload(single, token);
        }
    }

}
```

While that does make sure all the thread cooperate, logging in one at a time, it doesn't actually help me skip the expensive `authenticate()` step.

One other attempt I have made, which does meet the needs, is to do this:

```
public AsnycClient {

    private static HashMap<String, String> refreshedTokenMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    /* Credentials and other initializations */
    private static String token = null;
    @Async
    public uploadSingle(Single single){
        String currentToken = token;
        Result result = vendorClient.upload(single, currentToken);
        if( result.needsAuthentication()){
            synchronized (token){
                if( refreshedTokenMap.containsKey(currentToken)){
                    // the current token is one that has been renewed, and so 'token' will contain renewed value
                }else{
                    token = vendorClient.authenticate(credentials);
                    refreshedTokenMap.put(currentToken, token);
                }

            }
            result = vendorClient.upload(single, token);
        }
    }

}
```

Using that `refreshedTokenMap` I am able to tell if the token I started the function with has been renewed while in my current thread.
What  idon't have any way of is deleting entries in that `Map` once all the threads using the original token have finished executing.

Does anyone have an good resources that have solved this problem, or other guidance?

thanks.

Comment: The answer is easy, instead of using a simple HashMap, use or create a cache implementation that supports Time based eviction (like [guava](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CachesExplained), [ehCache](http://www.ehcache.org/documentation/2.7/configuration/data-life.html) or implement something similar to [this](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/io/ExpiringCache.java.html). In this way, your cache will drop your tokens and your code will simply regenerate them when does not find it in cache.

Comment: that's a good idea @m4gic   I know a token is only good for a maximum of 4 hours, so I can set that as an expiration time.  I still feel like I am missing something on the retry logic, that will help me minimize the number of failing requests, but the last sample I wrote does help me recover gracefully, if slightly more time consuming,

Comment: As an abstract I would just expect for request to fail @ some point and retry with new token. You can then improve that using logic to short-circuit in case of 100% expiration tokens. But when you are using time based logic there will always be and edge case where token is yet valid when you check its validity by time, and can be invalid when you actually use it.